# DNS 3rd party risks

Tags: dns

I'd like to know what are the risks having a subdomain managed by third party. For example, I manage my own DNS servers to serve `mydomain.example` which provide some internal and public content. If I develop a Cloud app on a Cloud provider and I want the domain for this app served by this Cloud provider, let's say `sub.mydomain.example`, what are the risks introduced to `mydomain.example` ? It could be takeover, reputation for the whole `mydomain.example`, or anything else ? Or maybe would it be preferable to serve `sub.mydomain.example` from my own DNS servers ?

Answer (score 3):

### Not directly: you can always revoke the delegation

DNS is a hierarchical system, where delegation of control is always given from the top to the next level. I like this illustration from SophieDogg's article [An Intro to DNS](https://sophiedogg.com/intro-to-dns/), because it recognize that some domains like `bbc.co.uk` are already from the same level of delegation than `sub.example.com`:

> [image: SophieDogg: Hierarchial View of the Domain Name System]

Therefore, if `sub.example.com` could affect `example.com` or `another.example.com`, all `*.co.uk` would be automatically in danger, too. Just like when your domain expires and the registrar managing `.com` domains is allowed to remove your delegation over `example.com` from the `com` name servers, you are at any time allowed to revoke the delegation over any `sub.example.com` simply by removing the `NS` records from the parent zone.

### However, there are some indirect risks

**Unlimited control over the whole subtree**

This is rather obvious, but you can't control the level of subdomains below the delegated subtree: if someone controls `sub.example.com`, he also controls `*.sub.example.com` `*.*.sub.example.com` and so on.

Remember that if someone controls the DNS, it's possible to add all type of records, whereas if you controlled it you could limit these possibilities e.g. only to `A` records. In addition, it's possible to return different answers to different clients, making it harder to debug issues or detect abuse.

**Subdomains with special functions**

You shouldn't allow registration of arbitrary subdomains, as some subdomains may have special use defined in a protocol. That kind of subdomains can affect the whole parent domain. E.g.

- *Underscored labels*; [RFC 8552](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8552), initial list in [section 4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8552#section-4.1.2), e.g.

  - `_acme-challenge` enables to get wildcard certificates using [DNS-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge)
  - `_domainkey` stores all DKIM keys ([RFC 5863, 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5863#section-4.1))
  - `_dmarc` is special for DMARC policies ([RFC 7489, 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-6.1))
  - `_tls`, `_tcp`, `_udp` that control `SRV` ([RFC 2782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782)) & `TLSA` ([RFC 6698](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6698#section-2)) records
- `wpad` used with *Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol* ([vulnerable](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/05/25/when-domain-names-attack-the-wpad-name-collision-vulnerability/) proxy auto-config)
- `autodiscover` is used by [Autodiscover service in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/autodiscover?view=exchserver-2019)

Carefully limit the allowed namespace!

**Protocols with cached properties**

This is essentially the same question than how a former owner of a domain can affect the domain you have just purchased. *HTTP Strict Transport Security* (HSTS, [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)) is a feature that is cached for a long time, and if someone enables HSTS on the domain, it can only be disabled over trusted (valid certificate) HTTPS on the next connection. *HTTP-Based Public Key Pinning* (HPKP, [RFC 7469](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7469)) was [removed from Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5903385005916160) partly for the same reasons i.e. the risk of denial of service and hostile pinning.

Problems within this category, as well as web site related problems like cookies that can be used from subdomains (`domain=.example.com`) aren't related to DNS delegation, but letting someone else use the subdomain on other protocols. Therefore, the same issues would exist even if you didn't delegate the control of the subdomain to 3rd party name servers.

**Subdomain takeovers**

The phenomenon is thoroughly explained in HackerOne's [Guide to Subdomain Takeovers](https://www.hackerone.com/blog/Guide-Subdomain-Takeovers). An abandoned subdomain could be used for malicious activities or a removed subdomain formerly in use could be re-registered to gain control over something someone else has forgotten behind. This can be prevented by disallowing re-use altogether or by applying long enough protection periods.

Comment: Thank you Esa for your reply. I read that main risks are : 
1) session leakage through cookies when they are valid for the whole`mydomain.example` and not only for `sub.mydomain.example` 
2) Script injection on `sub.mydomain.example` may have consequences on `mydomain.example` 
3) Cookie fixation if `evil.mydomain.example` sets a non host-only cookie at `mydomain.example` that my domain believes.
Are there any other risks I didn't see? And is there any possibility to take control over `mydomain.example`  managed by own DNS on-prem when `sub.mydomain.example` is managed by a Cloud provider?

Comment: I focused a bit more on the problems related to DNS delegation, as it gives full power over the subtree. The web site related security issues would exist despite you fully controlled the DNS. No, on DNS level you can't affect parent zone: as explained in the answer, if `sub.example.com` could compromise `example.com`, also `example.com` could compromise `com`.

Comment: You can have a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8552 for a registry of underscore labels.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: It would be so nice if special subdomains were limited to these underscore labeled, registered names! I found the `autodiscover`, but I bet there's more. Can you perhaps help me by adding some other unregistered, widely used subdomains? I mean those that are used in an automated manner and could easily be abused.

Comment: `wpad` is a pretty devastating example: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/05/25/when-domain-names-attack-the-wpad-name-collision-vulnerability/. but this is also mostly due in the underlying OS poor use of the DNS (it shouldn't recurse up to the root but would have to use something akin to the PSL to know where are the administrative boundaries, an unsolved problem in DNS land even today)

Comment: Nice, I'll add that one. Also, similar cases could be found e.g. by monitoring queries on a split DNS AD environment! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. And are risks introduced if my own internal DNS servers are recursive and redirect queries to  `sub.mydomain.example` to the Cloud provider DNS servers ?

Comment: The risks are technically the same, but the they are actually reduced, as 1) it's a fixed subdomain and 2) you are supposedly controlling the DNS through the cloud provider instead of allowing arbitrary modifications for a 3rd party actor.

Comment: It will be impossible to maintain an exhaustive up to date list, but since I have just stumbled on it: some clients may check for `lyncdiscoverinternal` or `lyncdiscover` names. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lyncserver/lync-server-2013-determine-dns-requirements?redirectedfrom=MSDN  (not sure if that it is still relevant today anyway)